# Convergence in distribution of the sum and multiplication of a random variable and a constant

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pFni.jpg)

I have a problem with c, that is a constant and it isn’t converges

Comment: Adding a constant to a random variable or multiplying by a constant is not particularly complicated: it is a location or scale change

Comment: Can I prove it by entering the constant in the definition of convergence in distribution to get the result ?

Comment: That would work, except perhaps for a negative multiplicative constant for a non-continuous random variable

Comment: Remember that if $B\in \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ then $\{X+c\in B\} = \{X\in B-c\}$ and $\{ cX\in B \} = \{ X\in (1/c)\cdot B \}, ~(c>0)$.